# RestKit returns empty array (0 objects) in -objectLoader:didLoadObjects:

Tags: objective-c, ios, object, mapping, restkit

I'm trying to use RestKit's object mapping, but the object loader just gives me an empty array.

I've tried

```
RKLogSetAppLoggingLevel(RKLogLevelTrace);
```

but I still don't get any output.

Here's what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spaces type="array">
  <space>
    <name>Brain Tuner</name>
    <default-showpage>Stream</default-showpage>
    <created-at type="datetime">2010-11-06T02:00:33+07:00</created-at>
    <is-commercial type="boolean">true</is-commercial>
    <watcher-permissions type="integer">1</watcher-permissions>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2011-08-12T14:07:55+07:00</updated-at>
    <wiki-name>braintuner</wiki-name>
    <team-permissions type="integer">2</team-permissions>
    <is-manager type="boolean">true</is-manager>
    <can-join type="boolean">false</can-join>
    <id>qwerty</id>
    <parent-id nil="true"></parent-id>
    <public-permissions type="integer">0</public-permissions>
    <description>Brain Tuner</description>
    <is-volunteer type="boolean">false</is-volunteer>
    <spaces-tools type="array">
      <spaces-tool type="GitTool">
        <created-at type="datetime">2011-07-08T09:44:43+07:00</created-at>
        <watcher-permissions type="integer" nil="true"></watcher-permissions>
        <url type="GitTool">giturl</url>
        <team-permissions type="integer" nil="true"></team-permissions>
        <id type="GitTool">asdfg</id>
        <tool-id type="integer">123</tool-id>
        <parent-id type="GitTool" nil="true"></parent-id>
        <public-permissions type="integer" nil="true"></public-permissions>
        <name type="GitTool">git2</name>
      </spaces-tool>
      <spaces-tool type="WikiTool">
        <created-at type="datetime">2010-11-06T02:00:33+07:00</created-at>
        <watcher-permissions type="integer" nil="true"></watcher-permissions>
        <url type="WikiTool" nil="true"></url>
        <team-permissions type="integer" nil="true"></team-permissions>
        <id type="WikiTool">zxcvbn</id>
        <tool-id type="integer">123</tool-id>
        <parent-id type="WikiTool" nil="true"></parent-id>
        <public-permissions type="integer" nil="true"></public-permissions>
        <name type="WikiTool">Wiki</name>
      </spaces-tool>
    </spaces-tools>
  </space>
</spaces>
```

Comment: The `RKLogSetAppLoggingLevel(RKLogLevelTrace);` sets log level for your app log statements, not for RestKit itself. Try this `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace);`

Comment: Find a solution? I'm monitoring the logs and I can the mapping happen successfully, but when didLoadObjects tries to load the NSArray of objects it's empty.